# IIS Force download of file extension ".rem" and not trigger error "There is no build provider registered for the extension '.rem'. "

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, web-config

THE PROBLEM:

Web application is serving various files that are downloaded, e.g. ".dwg", ".idw", etc. which are working fine.  In the web.config, there are  entries with "mimemap" for the extensions of known types.

For files with the extension ".rem" the following error is returned.

THE ERROR:

> There is no build provider registered for the extension '.rem'. You can register one in the  section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.

WORKAROUNDS TRIED:

1) Added two  entries to the web.config, but they do not have any effect (they do not work):

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".rem"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rem" mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
</staticContent>
```

2) The application is an MVC web app, and from what I read, adding "IgnoreRoute" *could* work, but I also read that it only works for files that are not physically on disk.  These ".rem" files **are** on disk.

ADDITIONAL THOUGHTS:

Looking at the error, one may be tempted to add a build provider, as suggested.  Files with extension ".rem" need to be downloaded, and not built like a .aspx with a code-behind .cs file or .cshtml, etc.

SOLUTION (10/9/2018):
The solution provided below by Dadeke is also what was provided by Microsoft to resolve the issue.

Part of email from Microsoft:
When an object is hosted in Internet Information Services (IIS), the objectUri extension must be .soap or .rem, so that the request is routed to the .NET Remoting IHttpHandler. There are handler mappings by default for .rem. That’s the reason it behaves differently than other downloadable files.

Here are the steps to make it downloadable:

1. Remove all .rem from IIS Handler mappings.

   ```
   <handlers>
       <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
       <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
       <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-2.0-64" />
       <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-2.0" />
       <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-Integrated-4.0" />
       <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-Integrated" />
   </handlers>
   ```
2. Add MIME type as below:

   ```
   <mimeMap fileExtension="*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
   ```
3. Make a change in the link on default.html as below:
   Files/TextFile1.rem
   (I was able to simply add "download" to the anchor tag -  - without the name of the file.) YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

The **".rem"** extension is quite common for CNAB 240 and CNAB 400 remittance files at banks in Brazil.
Only text is used in your content.

**CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM:**

The **".rem"** extension is added by default in **"Handler Mappings"** in IIS.
Look:

[image: Handler Mappings in IIS]

**SOLUTION:**

Add instructions in **web.config** to disable the **".rem"** extension handlers.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <!-- Force download extension ".rem". -->
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".rem" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
        <!-- Remove handlers mappings extension ".rem" -->
        <handlers>
            <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
            <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-Integrated" />
            <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-2.0" />
            <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-2.0-64" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This will force the download of all files with the extension **".rem"**

It worked for me. \o/

Comment: Thank you for the reply and solution.
This was given to me by Microsoft after many other failed suggestions.  Apparently, .rem extensions are reserved, as you point out, and adding the handler removals as you suggest do work.